# How do you apply the same javascript code to multiple questions in Qualtrics survey?

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I have some javascript in one of my survey questions that changes the formatting of a certain field. It works great, but I would like to apply the same code to several other questions. Obviously, I can simply copy and paste onto each question, but is there any way to have the code set in a single location so that it is more maintainable? I've looked on a number of forums but haven't been able to find a solution. Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT:
Here is the JavaScript code that I would like to be repeated for multiple questions:

```
{
    /*Place your JavaScript here to run when the page is fully displayed*/
    jQuery("#"+this.questionId+" select option:first-child").text("Select one");    

    jQuery("#"+ this.questionId + " option").each(function () {
            if (jQuery(this).text().includes("\"\"")) {
                jQuery(this).hide();    
            }else{
                title = jQuery(this).text()
                title = title.match(/".*"/)
                if(title != null && title[0].length > 30){
                    newTitle = title[0].match(/^.{30}.*?\s/)[0]
                    if(newTitle != title){
                        newTitle = newTitle + "...\""
                    }
                    text = jQuery(this).text()
                    jQuery(this).text(text.replace(title[0],newTitle))
                }   
            }
    });

});
```

Basically, there is some embedded data preloaded for each contact, and several questions involve a dropdown menu that allows users to select which of their data elements was relevant to a project. This code ensures that blank or missing data does not get included in the dropdown, and also if the option is too many characters long, it gets truncated. Multiple questions include the same dropdown options, but differ in other ways.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your work? Hard to imagine your implementation, but in general to answer your question, yes there is a way.

Comment: @kemicofa Thanks for the response. I've edited my post to include a code sample and description of what it is I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your code a function and put it in the Qualtrics header.  Call the function from each question where it applies.

In the header:

```
<script>
myFunction(qobj) {
   jQuery("#"+qobj.questionId+" select option:first-child")...etc...
}
</script>
```

Then in your questions:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
  myFunction(this);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the same class to each of your question (I chose `myQuestion` class) then query it.

Loop through each select and `find` the `option:first-child` and then `find` the `option`s and loop through each of them.

```js
$('.myQuestion select').each(function(selectIndex, select){

  // loop through each select
  // for each select find all the options
  
  $(this).find("option:first-child").text("Select one");
  
  $(this).find('option').each(function(optionIndex, option){
    console.log(`select (${selectIndex}) | option (${optionIndex})`);
    
    // your code here
    
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myQuestion">
  <select>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select> 
</div>

<div class="myQuestion">
  <select>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select> 
</div>
```

Comment: This looks like a great jQuery solution in general, but I can't find a way to assign a class to questions in Qualtrics using their UI. It seems to only let me modify the HTML of the question text which does not include the <div> that contains the answer selections.